# What is the word for something that is non-divisible in development context?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, adjectives, programming

I'm looking for a generic word, an adjective, that means non-divisible. Like the opposite of compound.

I am looking for a word I can use in the context of programming, where you can have data types that are compound of other data types. I want a word to identify the "indivisible" data types.

Comment: **indivisible**

Comment: monomorphemic .

Comment: ‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎atomic

Comment: I guess perhaps I asked in the wrong forum. I was looking for something in the context of programming where you can have data types that are compound of other data types. I wanted a word to identify the "indivisible" data types. But I guess indivisible will have to do for now.

Comment: @tchrist I think you just hit the nail on the head. Perhaps my question should have had some context injected. Thanks. Please answer to I can accept :)

Comment: "Avoid answering questions in comments".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The best word for something that cannot be split in a programming context is [*atomic*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearizability).

This is used a lot, and is essential for interruptible programming.  For example, in [a signal handler](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/glibc-manual-0.02/library_21.html#SEC358) you should only touch variables of type [**sig_*atomic*_t**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606725/linux-why-is-sig-atomic-t-typedefed-to-int) and storage class `volatile`, as explained [here](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/glibc-manual-0.02/library_21.html#SEC358).

Comment: It also works in physics and logic and pretty much anything else.

Comment: Could `const` type strings be considered "atomic" ?

Comment: *Atomic* literally means indivisible (*a-*, negation, and *tomos* meaning "cut", "cutting" or "section").

Comment: I'm more used to hearing "atomic" used for _operations_ in programming, in the sense that an atomic operation can't be interrupted. So it's indivisible in _time_, not memory or program structure. An atomic data type would just be one that it's possible to perform atomic operations on.

Comment: @DavidZ Indeed. I don’t think I understood what he meant at first. Your answer of *primitive data types* is better.  There is a `sig_atomic_t` as I mentioned, but that has a rather restricted use.

Comment: I've seen *atomic* used both for operations and for storage. Both of your answers are excellent. +1

Answer (score 11):

Quoting from your comment:

> I was looking for something in the context of programming where you can have data types that are compound of other data types. I wanted a word to identify the "indivisible" data types.

It sounds like you're asking for a word to describe types like `int`, `double`, `char`, etc. in most programming languages. The most common term I've heard for those is [**primitive**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_data_type). Some other languages identify them as "built-in" or "basic," but "primitive" is most likely to be recognized by the majority of developers (across all languages) as a term for what you're talking about.

In other contexts, "primitive" would probably not be used to designate an indivisible object. You'd be more likely to hear "indivisible" itself, "fundamental," or "atomic."

Comment: [Primitive data type](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Primitive-Types) is a good answer, because that is the term used by The Standard.

Comment: @tchrist It seems a poor assumption that the language must be C or C++, but anyway no, the term *primitive* is not used (in reference to types) in those standards. There are *scalar* types though, and C has *atomic* types.

Answer (score 9):

Consider the adjective, *indivisible*, and its synonyms: inseparable, indissoluble, undividable.

**Edit**: In programming, you can refer to [atomic types](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/atomic/).

Comment: Are you sure that’s not just some Microsoft thing?

Comment: atomic in programming refers not to the indivisibility of contents but to the indivisibility of read-modify-write cycle used in modification.

Comment: @Jim Careful there. You've forgotten to account for consistent, isolated and durable.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch- You, of course, are talking about the term ACID, in which the *A* stands for atomicity.  The reason the other 3 letters are there is because the *A* does not include those attributes.

Answer (score 5):

Another possibility: A [quantum](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/quantum) is a discrete quantity that cannot be subdivided. It is also used as an adjective: *quantum* leap.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the term "[**indissociable**](https://www.wordnik.com/words/indissociable)"

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking data types, those that are not composite are usually known as *fundamental*, e.g. in C and C++.

Comment: No, they aren’t.  They are called [primitive types](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Primitive-Types).

Comment: @tchrist That's the manual for GCC, not the language standard. However, pointers are composite and not fundamental so it's probably not the difference OP is thinking of.

Answer (score 1):

Often, a good antonym for *compound* is *[irreducible](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/irreducible#irreducible)*:

> Not able to be reduced or simplified (Oxford Dictionaries)

Another word you might consider is *[simple](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/simple),* although it does have other meanings that might make it too vague for your purposes:

> Composed of a single element; not compound. (Oxford Dictionaries)

Answer (score -1):

**Onea**: [having the indivisible character of a unit](http://www.rhymezone.com/r/rhyme.cgi?Word=onea)

**Monad**:  [technical     1A single unit; the number one.](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/monad)

**Insecable**: [Incapable of being divided by a cutting instrument; indivisible.](https://www.wordnik.com/words/insecable)

Comment: Googling for "insecable", and excluding dictionaries, reveals that it mainly comes up in English translations of text from languages where it's a more common word, or quotations of untranslated text. Also it is used to describe non-breaking spaces in typography. IMO it doesn't belong in the dictionary, at least with such a general definition… you can't expect anyone to just know the word.

Comment: A usageaster whose expertise is from google....how interesting ;-)

Comment: Perhaps, but honestly have you ever seen this word in real usage or did you just get it from a reference? It's not in Webster's or Oxford American dictionaries, but it is fairly common in French. I seriously suspect it's not an English word but just made it into some dictionaries by data-mining.

Comment: I like 'monad', but technically, the point of a monad is that it is a **completed** totality.  In particular, it's made up of opposites.

Comment: I can find no other evidence that "onea" is a word with this meaning, and it also looks quite odd.