# What is a word to describe something which cannot be broken down any further?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I don't want to use the word *elemental,* nor *axiomatic,* as both terms are already defined and in popular use.

Anyway, the way I want to use the term is not to describe the part, or type of part itself, but the quality that the part possesses; 'Something with which cannot be broken down any further possesses the quality x', where x is the word I seek, in the same way an axiom has the quality of being axiomatic.

Comment: essence/essential - "broken into its essential parts"

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question but *atomic* is described as "of or forming a single irreducible unit or component in a larger system", and it's corresponding noun would be *atomicity*. Does that come close to what you were looking for?

Comment: @Yay Ah yes, Atomic, I do not know why that didn't come to mind. Thanks ^.^

Comment: @Yay you know what, i'm gonna go with atomicity, you should include it add as an answer :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the word for something that is non-divisible?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/166466/what-is-the-word-for-something-that-is-non-divisible)

Comment: If anything, that should be *this* questions dupe, as this one now contains the definition of *atomic* that I was unaware of (and that one doesn't; just a link).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think that the word *atomic*, which is often otherwise used in a physical sense, should be used here.

> **atomic** a·tom·ic /əˈtämik/ *adjective*
>
> - of or relating to an atom or atoms. *"the atomic nucleus"*
> - *Chemistry* (of a substance) consisting of uncombined atoms rather than molecules. *"atomic hydrogen"*
> - **of or forming a single irreducible unit or component in a larger system.**
>
> –[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/atomic)

Comment: I see the definition, but "atomic" is not the word that comes to mind when I contemplate things that can't be broken down any further. The ancient Greeks coined the term *atom*, but we now know that atoms can be broken down into protons, neutrons, and electrons, and that protons and neutrons can be broken down further into quarks. We talk of "splitting the atom".

Comment: But if it works for the OP, that's what matters!

Comment: @RichardKayser That’s hardly the fault of the Greeks. _Atomic_ literally means ‘uncuttable’ (i.e., ‘unable to be cut/split up into smaller pieces’) – we were just too quick to apply it to a tiny thing in physics, not knowing that the thing we were thus (mis)naming was in fact **not** atomic. To me, _atomic_ is absolutely a word I’d think of when I contemplate things that can’t be broken down any further.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet  Agreed. And when we find the new word **sub-atomic**, *atomic* there refers to the thing we thought was atomic, but actually wasn't.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet  Agreed. And when we find the new word **sub-atomic**, *atomic* there refers to the thing we thought was atomic, but actually wasn't.

Comment: Why is the site acting wacky today? I'm sometimes getting messages that there was an error saving my comment, and just then there was no error, but the comment was saved twice.  Is that Einstein's spooky actions at a distance? *spukhafte Fernwirkungen*

Answer (score 4):

I'd go for **irreducible**, "not reducible; incapable of being reduced or of being diminished or simplified further".

Answer (score 3):

While I agree that *atomic* may be the best fit, ***indecomposable*** works too.

M-W:

> **[indecomposable](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/indecomposable)**
>   *adjective*
>
> :  not capable of being separated into component parts or elements

Answer (score 0):

"Simplex" is another one that would work.

"Simplex" derives from the same root as "simple," but is used more exclusively in the technical sense of being irreducible in form. I think "simplicity" is the noun form of both. It can be used to mean, "Freedom from division into parts."

Answer (score 0):

I try to get to the ***root*** of the problem. The ***root*** of any problem exists as the basis for all resulting and related things and issues.

The ***root*** of a word is the basis of its evolution and usage in our language.

Mathematically, a ***root*** is a component of an amount, part of a denominator, a multiplicand.

The ***root*** is elemental

Comment: A prime number used to be a number that could not be broken down any further. Then the algebraists began to insist that 1 is not a prime.

Answer (score 0):

indiscrete: not discrete : not separated into distinct parts

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Not really.  You can have a discrete group, which would be divisible.

Answer (score -1):

**Ineffable**:

> that cannot be expressed or described in language. (OED)

Comment: add a citation or dictionary ref to your answer if you please.

Comment: I think this doesn't really fit, since an atom for example cannot be broken down any further, but that doesn't make it ineffable.